# How can I assign events in pure functional way?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, dom-events

How I can rewrite this code in pure functional way?

```
let counter = 0    
const link = document.querySelector('a')    
link.addEventListener('click', () => {    
  console.log(counter++)    
})
```

Comment: You cannot. Manipulations of the dom like adding event listners are mutating the object.

Comment: You need a language that can express event streams and behaviors (time-varying values/functions), techniques that are subsumed under the term functional reactive programming. I am far from being an expert but I think there are FRP libs out there in the JS community, which implement these techniques at least partially.